# How to search something on across multiple sites with a single Google query?

Tags: google-search

I tried

- `(search term site:stackoverflow.com) OR (search term site:superuser.com) OR (search term site:stackexchange.com)`
- `search term site:stackoverflow.com,superuser.com,stackexchange.com`
- `search term site:stackoverflow.com site:superuser.com site:stackexchange.com`

None of them works. What is the correct way to search?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After a bit of experimenting, it appears you can do this by putting the `OR` operator between the sites:

```
search site:stackoverflow.com OR site:superuser.com OR site:stackexchange.com
```

This gives you results from any of the sites.

---

If you do this kind of search frequently on the same set of sites, you can create a [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.co.uk/cse/). You add the sites you want to search to it and it gives you a url to go to when you want to do a search. All searches from this url only contain results from the configured sites.