# Possible to specify multiple sites to search using Bing?

Tags: search, search-engine, bing

If I want to search the site `mysite.com` on Bing, I can type:

```
my search terms site:mysite.com
```

Is there a way to specify multiple sites to search? I've tried:

```
my search terms site:mysite.com,othersite.com
```

and

```
my search terms site:mysite.com site:othersite.com
```

but neither worked. Can it be done?

Answer (score 3):

```
my search terms site:mysite.com OR site:othersite.com
```

Google and Blekko don’t need the `OR`, Bing does.

Comment: Are you sure about the implicit "OR" at Google? The query "performance site:stackoverflow.com site:programmers.stackexchange.com" did not return any results, whereas leaving out either "site:" returned results in both cases.

Comment: Is using multiple domains in a Google search even possible?

Comment: The AND seems to be implied for a Google search. The query "legacy  site:stackoverflow.com  OR site:programmers.stackexchange.com" returns results from both domains, *stackoverflow.com* and *programmers.stackexchange.com*. Leaving out "OR" does not return any results.

Comment: It is covered in *[How to search something on across multiple sites with a single Google query?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6217)*.