# How to search multiple sites with Google and get random results?

Tags: google-search, javascript

I'm trying to find examples of English collocations in a set of sites. I know how to search in multiple sites as it's been solved here [before](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6217/).

```
search term site:A OR site:B OR site:C
```

The problem is that Google shows all the results of site A then site B and it kind of defeats the purpose of searching multiple sites at the same time because you have to go through all the results of site A to get to site B results.

Is there any way (for example a JavaScript code?) to make Google results shown randomly so that I can have examples from all the sites in the first 100 results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Search results are outputted based on page rank so all depends on the search term (eg. statement that sites are grouped is not true):

```
"google sheets" site:webapps.stackexchange.com OR site:stackoverflow.com
```

[image: 0]

Also, you can always try alternative search engines like DuckDuckGo, Yandex or Bing